# Error [nuxt] instance unavailable when using useRuntimeConfig in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I'm trying to get some environnement variables that I set in my nuxt.config.ts like this :

```
  const config = {
    space: useRuntimeConfig().public.CTF_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: useRuntimeConfig().public.CTF_CDA_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    host: useRuntimeConfig().public.CTF_HOST,
    environment: useRuntimeConfig().public.CTF_ENVIRONMENT
  };
```

But when I run npm run generate, I have an error :

```
Error [nuxt] instance unavailable
```

From what I understand, I can't access `useRuntimeConfig()` wth `ssr: true`. But how should I do it ?

Comment: Where exactly do you use useRuntimeConfig? The error means that you use it in a wrong place, the question requires the context